# How to i18n ic_launcher icon?

Tags: android, internationalization, icons

I searched the net but did not find a resource for this.

I want to localize my ic_launcher app icon. Since I only have the mipmap folder I first tried to add a (parallel) folder called `mipmap-xxxhdpi-de` on the same folder level as `mipmap-xxxhdpi` in the project structure. However, when I compile the app I get an error message.

So, how do I i18n my app icon?

Comment: I think the -de is the problem. If you right click the res directory new android resource directory and let it guide you as many sizes, orientations, languages etc that you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put language identifier before size:

```
mipmap-de-xxxhdpi
```